# Unable to enable billing for Google App Engine application - Error enabling cloud integration

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, billing

Having created a number of Google App Engine applications and later enabled billing via the App Engine interface in the past, I am now unable to do this for a new application since it appears that new App Engine applications now must be administered through the Google Developer Console.

Within the Google App Engine interface (appengine.google.com), it informs me:

> Billing for this application is managed from the Google Cloud Console.

and then further directs:

> Create a Google Cloud project as well as a Google Cloud Storage bucket and a new style service account for this application

however every time this is attempted it reports:

> An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.

If I instead access the Google Developer Console (console.developers.google.com), I can see that a new project has been created (presumably from the above action) for this application however if I try to open it I receive the message "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page." and yet I am the admin account and presumably created this project. This leaves me unable to administer or enable billing for the application. My other applications are all listed in this interface and I can freely open them and see their details, it is just the new project.

Is it possible to either correct the permissions for this application so it can be accessed from the Google Developer Console or can I instead have the billing for this application controlled and enabled from the Google App Engine interface?

I am happy to privately provide the Google application-id if this is required for further diagnosis.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Further Note: I have come across this which could be related, https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9602, which indicates there has been problems in the past with this facility but Google have marked this issue closed.

Comment: hey @Simon have you been able to find out what was the problem in your case?